# Mutiple .txt list to data frame in r

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a folder with 44 .txt files (.../data). I want to collect the data contained in all those 44 files in just one data frame. This is what I have done:

```
setwd("/Users/setegonz/MEGAsync/ProjetoUFABC-master/results")
library(tidyverse)
list_of_files <- list.files(path = "/Users/setegonz/MEGAsync/ProjetoUFABC-master/data", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE)

df <- list_of_files %>%
  set_names(.) %>%
  map_df(., read_table, .id = "FileName")
```

This is my output:

[image]

I would like to achieve two things:
1. Two separate all the variables that I have grouped in the second column, into individual columns.
2. Two shorten the identification name to somthing like "sub_01", "sub_2", and so on.

I would like to achieve this by using a tidiverse approach.

Thanks!

Comment: [separate](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) should be helpful to split your columns up. I would just use `gsub()` to replace all the repetitive text in the ID column.

Comment: `df <- list_of_files %>%
  set_names(.) %>%
  map_dfr(., read_table, .id = "FileName") %>%
  separate(., c(2), ",")`
 
gives me me this :
http://snpy.in/Zz53jz

Now I have multiple columns but all of them with all the variables together.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [map_dfr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) which takes a a list and returns a data frame with the results row-bound together. 
Here's an example:

```
tibble(a = seq(1,10)) %>% write_csv("tmp.csv")
rep("tmp.csv", 3) %>% map_dfr(., read_csv)
```

The final command returns a data frame that has 30 rows (3 copies of tmp.csv). I suspect that:

```
map_dfr(list_of_files, read_csv)
```

will do exactly what you want.

Comment: map_dfr gives me the same results as map_df